# Using a specific zmm register in inline asm

Tags: gcc, assembly, x86, inline-assembly

Can I tell [gcc-style inline assembly](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html) to put my `__m512i` variable into a *specific* `zmm` register, like `zmm31`?

Comment: Do [Local Variable Registers](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Local-Register-Variables.html) support them?

Comment: Are you sure you need to?  Obviously you want to make sure it's not going to put the value in one of the other zmm registers that you're going to be using in the asm, but presumably those are getting clobbered, and gcc already won't put the value there.  If local variable registers won't work, I suppose you could clobber all the zmm registers *except* zmm31.  While there's a limit on the number of input+output parameters, I don't know of any limit on the number of clobbers (which doesn't mean there isn't one...).

Comment: @MichaelPetch: I just tried it: https://godbolt.org/z/oMnFEA. `register __m512i z31 asm("zmm31");` works with clang, but gcc seems to have a bug that makes it use zmm31 temporarily, but then put the input in a different register for the actual `asm` statement.

Comment: @PeterCordes You need to use the "v" constraint. The "x" constraint only allows the first 16 SIMD registers.

Comment: @RossRidge: Thanks, that's what I was missing.

Comment: @DavidWohlferd - yes, in this case I want to test a difference in behavior between `zmm{0-15}` and `zmm{16-31}`. So actually a constraint that let me put the value in any of the "upper" zmm registers would also work (kind of the opposite of `x`) in my specific case - but I asked the more general question.

Answer (score 6):

Like on targets where the are no specific-register constraints at all (like ARM), use [local register variables](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Local-Register-Variables.html) to get broad constraints to pick a specific register for `asm` statements.  The compiler can still optimize otherwise, because the only documented *guaranteed* effect of a register-local is for `asm` inputs/outputs.

The compiler will *prefer* the specified register even if there's no `asm`, though.  (So you can write code that appears to work but isn't safe in general with stuff like `register int ebx asm("ebx");  return ebx;`.  GCC documentation is what makes a behaviour guaranteed / future-proof, even if current gcc prefers using the specified register strongly enough to waste instructions when the constraint isn't compatible with the specified register, see below.)

**Anyway, this use of register-asm *local* variables is the *only* thing they're guaranteed to work for**:

```
#include <immintrin.h>
__m512i foo() {
    register __m512i z31 asm("zmm31") = _mm512_set1_epi32(123);
    register __m512i z30 asm("zmm30");

    asm("vmovdqa64 %1, %0  # from inline asm"
        : "=v"(z30)
        : "v"(z31)
       );
    return z30;
}
```

On [the Godbolt compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,source:'%23include+%3Cimmintrin.h%3E%0A__m512i+foo()+%7B%0A++++register+__m512i+z31+asm(%22zmm31%22)+%3D+_mm512_set1_epi32(123)%3B%0A++++register+__m512i+z30+asm(%22zmm30%22)%3B%0A%0A++++asm(%22vmovdqa64+%251,+%250++%23+from+inline+asm%22%0A++++++++:+%22%3D%26v%22(z30)%0A++++++++:+%22v%22(z31)%0A+++++++)%3B%0A++++return+z30%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A%23ifndef+__clang__%0A__m512i+broken_with_clang()+%7B%0A++++register+__m512i+z31+asm(%22zmm31%22)+%3D+_mm512_set1_epi32(123)%3B%0A++++register+__m512i+z30+asm(%22zmm30%22)+%3D+_mm512_setzero_si512()%3B%0A++++//+notice+that+gcc+still+inits+these+in+zmm31+and+30,+*then*+copies%0A++++//+so+register+asm+costs+us+efficiency.%0A%0A++++//+AVX512+only+has+compares+into+k+registers,+not+into+YMM+registers.%0A++++asm(%22vpcmpeqd+%25t1,+%25t0,+%25t0++%23+from+inline+asm.+input+was+%250%22%0A++++++++:+%22%2Bx%22(z30)%0A++++++++:+%22x%22(z31)%0A+++++++)%3B%0A++++return+z30%3B%0A%7D%0A%23endif'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:50,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang_trunk,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'1',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-O3+-Wall+-march%3Dskylake-avx512',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+clang+(trunk)+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),k:50,l:'4',m:33.333333333333336,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:1,editor:1,wrap:'1'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'%231+with+x86-64+clang+(trunk)',t:'0')),header:(),l:'4',m:17.220543806646525,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g82,filters:(b:'0',binary:'1',commentOnly:'0',demangle:'0',directives:'0',execute:'1',intel:'1',trim:'1'),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:'-O3+-Wall+-march%3Dskylake-avx512',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+gcc+8.2+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%232)+C%2B%2B',t:'0')),l:'4',m:49.44612286002013,n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),k:50,l:'3',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4), compiles to this with clang6.0:

```
    # clang -O3 -march=skylake-avx512
    vbroadcastss    .LCPI0_0(%rip), %zmm31 # zmm31 = [1.72359711E-43,1.72359711E-43,1.72359711E-43,1.72359711E-43,1.72359711E-43,1.72359711E-43,1.72359711E-43,1.72359711E-43,1.72359711E-43,1.72359711E-43,1.72359711E-43,1.72359711E-43,1.72359711E-43,1.72359711E-43,1.72359711E-43,1.72359711E-43]
    vmovdqa64       %zmm31, %zmm30        # from inline asm
    vmovaps %zmm30, %zmm0
    retq
```

and gcc8.2:

```
# gcc -O3 -march=skylake-avx512
foo():
    movl    $123, %eax
    vpbroadcastd    %eax, %zmm31
    vmovdqa64 %zmm31, %zmm30  # from inline asm
    vmovdqa64       %zmm30, %zmm0
    ret
```

---

**Note the `"v"` constraints** which allow any EVEX vector register (0..31), unlike `"x"` which only allows the first 16.  `"x"` is documented as "any SSE register", but also applies to AVX YMM registers.  https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Machine-Constraints.html.

Using `"x"` for this didn't result in any warnings, but with gcc `"x"` won vs. the register-variable declaration, so it chose %zmm2 and %zmm1 (strangely not `zmm0` so an extra move was required).  The register-asm declaration thus did cost us efficiency.

With clang it still used zmm31 and zmm30, apparently violating the `"x"` constraint, so it would have failed to assemble if you'd used an instruction with no EVEX version on the XMM or YMM part of the register operand, like AVX2 [`vpcmpeqd ymm,ymm,ymm`](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/PCMPEQB:PCMPEQW:PCMPEQD.html) (compare into vector, not compare into mask). ([In GNU C inline asm, what're the modifiers for xmm/ymm/zmm for a single operand?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34459803/in-gnu-c-inline-asm-whatre-the-modifiers-for-xmm-ymm-zmm-for-a-single-operand)).

```
//#ifndef __clang__
__m512i broken_with_clang() {
    register __m512i z31 asm("zmm31") = _mm512_set1_epi32(123);
    register __m512i z30 asm("zmm30") = _mm512_setzero_si512();
    // notice that gcc still inits these in zmm31 and 30, *then* copies
    // so register asm costs us efficiency.

    // AVX512 only has compares into k registers, not into YMM registers.
    asm("vpcmpeqd %t1, %t0, %t0  # from inline asm. input was %0"
        : "+x"(z30)
        : "x"(z31)
       );
    return z30;
}
//#endif
```

With clang we get an error for each operand; I guess clang doesn't support `t` modifiers to get the YMM name of the register (because it fails with clang6.0 even if I remove the `register ... asm()` stuff entirely.)

```
<source>:21:9: error: invalid operand in inline asm: 'vpcmpeqd ${1:t}, ${0:t}, ${0:t}  # from inline asm. input was $0'
    asm("vpcmpeqd %t1, %t0, %t0  # from inline asm. input was %0"
        ^
...
<source>:21:9: error: unknown token in expression
<inline asm>:1:11: note: instantiated into assembly here
        vpcmpeqd , ,   # from inline asm. input was %zmm30
```

But gcc compiles it just fine:

```
broken_with_clang():
    movl    $123, %eax
    vpbroadcastd    %eax, %zmm31
    vpxord  %xmm30, %xmm30, %xmm30

    vmovdqa64       %zmm30, %zmm1    # extra overhead because of register asm
    vmovdqa64       %zmm31, %zmm2    # which didn't match the constraints

    vpcmpeqd %ymm2, %ymm1, %ymm1  # from inline asm. input was %zmm1

    vmovdqa64       %zmm1, %zmm0     # extra overhead because gcc didn't pick zmm0
    ret
```

Comment: There was some hesitation about adding "The only supported use for this feature is to specify registers for input and output operands when calling Extended asm" to the "new" asm docs. My phrasing here was deliberately provocative (only?!?), with the intent of smoking out any other supported usages so I could doc them or offer them as examples. Eventually it was conceded that there weren't any, and a whole category of potential bugs were explicitly and unambiguously described as not being supported.  Doesn't stop people from trying, but when it doesn't work, there's a (linkable) clue as to why.