# GNU C inline asm input constraint for AVX512 mask registers (k1...k7)?

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, inline-assembly, avx512

AVX512 introduced opmask feature for its arithmetic commands. A simple example: [godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org/z/P7xWD8).

```
#include <immintrin.h>
__m512i add(__m512i a, __m512i b) {
    __m512i sum;
    asm(
        "mov ebx, 0xAAAAAAAA;                                   \n\t"
        "kmovw k1, ebx;                                         \n\t"
        "vpaddd %[SUM] %{k1%}%{z%}, %[A], %[B];  # conditional add   "
        :   [SUM]   "=v"(sum)
        :   [A]     "v" (a),
            [B]     "v" (b)
        : "ebx", "k1"  // clobbers
       );
    return sum;
}
```

---

```
-march=skylake-avx512 -masm=intel -O3
```

---

```
 mov ebx,0xaaaaaaaa
 kmovw k1,ebx
 vpaddd zmm0{k1}{z},zmm0,zmm1
```

---

The problem is that k1 has to be specified.

Is there an input constraint like `"r"` for integers except that it picks a `k` register instead of a general-purpose register?

Comment: How about `Yk`? From [here](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/gcc/config/i386/constraints.md#L81).

Comment: bug fixed by adding {z}.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`__mmask16` is literally a typedef for `unsigned short` (and other mask types for other plain integer types), so we just need a constraint for passing it in a `k` register.

---

We have to go digging in the gcc sources [`config/i386/constraints.md`](https://gcc.gnu.org/viewcvs/gcc/trunk/gcc/config/i386/constraints.md?view=co&content-type=text%2Fplain) to find it:

The constraint for *any* mask register is `"k"`.  **Or use `"Yk"` for `k1..k7` (which can be used as a predicate, unlike `k0`).**  You'd use an `"=k"` operand as the destination for a compare-into-mask, for example.

Obviously you can use `"=Yk"(tmp)` with a `__mmask16 tmp` to get the compiler to do register allocation for you, instead of just declaring clobbers on whichever `"k"` registers you decide to use.

---

#### Prefer intrinsics like `_mm512_maskz_add_epi32`

First of all, **https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/DontUseInlineAsm** if you can avoid it.  *Understanding* asm is great, but use that to read compiler output and/or figure out what would be optimal, then write intrinsics that can compile the way you want.  Performance tuning info like https://agner.org/optimize/ and https://uops.info/ list things by asm mnemonic, and they're shorter / easier to remember than intrinsics, but you can search by mnemonic to find intrinsics on https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/

Intrinsics will also let the compiler fold loads into memory source operands for other instructions; with AVX512 those can even be broadcast loads!  Your inline asm forces the compiler to use a separate load instruction.  **Even a `"vm"` input won't let the compiler pick a broadcast-load as the memory source**, because it wouldn't know the broadcast element width of the instruction(s) you were using it with.

**Use `_mm512_mask_add_epi32` or `_mm512_maskz_add_epi32`** especially if you're already using `__m512i` types from `<immintrin.h>`.

---

Also, **your asm has a bug: you're using `{k1}` merge-masking not `{k1}{z}` zero-masking**, but you used uninitialized `__m512i sum;` with an output-only `"=v"` constraint as the merge destination!  As a stand-alone function, it happens to merge into `a` because the calling convention has ZMM0 = first input = return value register.  But when inlining into other functions, you definitely can't assume that `sum` will pick the same register as `a`.  Your best bet is to use a read/write operand for `"+v"(a)` and use is as the destination and first source.

**Merge-masking only makes sense with a `"+v"` read/write operand.**  (Or in an asm statement with multiple instructions where you've already written an output once, and want to merge another result into it.)

Intrinsics would stop you from making this mistake; the merge-masking version has an extra input for the merge-target.  (The asm destination operand).

---

#### Example using "Yk"

```
// works with -march=skylake-avx512 or -march=knl
// or just -mavx512f but don't do that.
// also needed: -masm=intel
#include <immintrin.h>
__m512i add_zmask(__m512i a, __m512i b) {
    __m512i sum;
    asm(
        "vpaddd %[SUM] %{%[mask]%}%{z%}, %[A], %[B];  # conditional add   "
        :   [SUM]   "=v"(sum)
        :   [A]     "v" (a),
            [B]     "v" (b),
            [mask]  "Yk" ((__mmask16)0xAAAA)
         // no clobbers needed, unlike your question which I fixed with an edit
       );
    return sum;
}
```

Note that all the `{` and `}` are escaped with `%` (https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html#Special-format-strings), so they're not parsed as dialect-alternatives `{AT&T | Intel-syntax}`.

This compiles with gcc as early as 4.9, but don't actually do that because it doesn't understand `-march=skylake-avx512`, or even have tuning settings for Skylake or KNL.  Use a more recent GCC that knows about your CPU for best results.

[**Godbolt compiler explorer**](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAM1QDsCBlZAQwBtMQBGAOgCYAOAJyCALAFYADPwDswucNIArLqVbNaoZAFJeAIR27SAZ1QBXYsg4ByHQGY8tZK1NYA1FtsBhPAFsfDgmIHbgQPbC0JAEEIyIB9WJ8xTl48V2Z0dFiALx9mIwBrCHjE5NTmUldipJTXACMASndpfSjXNsqE6tSjUx8PFsj2tKMfCBihoZ1eADcAB3SM914xLTFdBgBVAFlVgBElleadFbXcgr3jrWldy%2Bas292Ky7XosUeD1d19N/62u1c0LR8AQ8HQ2GlFn9eLxxhM2iB2p9Njs3ojoR5dtMphAej56rC4Qi/i89hMpljoa4IMx6qQCXDEWtvvtJtCKbwqQ06a0GUMAPR8z5nfKkpa8ACaIspEAkAA9IgrFQrGq4Ba5iJgAI6mPAaoyuSIANQAGtVdAB1VyYaaYWiuPBUVwEBCYAF0IwEdQEVwAdzMrHQriohHtds4ADY6oQjBVapgWKYjK7aswNaGCJhgJhiK5WIRs2x9QhmDanQBPWaugL03lCvIi1FiyVTKlFBLCiP1OVK/E8wmqvli/KcFsD4DIZC%2BvCsViuWZ4ZD5NKufBUKjZ23e4XqzP2x0%2B11YJyp13MAGsVC1OM5uiuOiYGttfG2AZDDUEcx23H9GJXG5RGIqlKCFMkwWVZjzZBCDbEoanKDpYNSBomlfdogJqb8X3pPJRkfKFeB8VBpitWpZQqbslUVX5eRo2iGVWTxaAYggpjwodCOmH1XGHCpMFI6i6MEoTGUY5jWL7Mk2XmDJA2edZtlJW5dGHB4nmWT5XneOTmWo/5AWBUFaHBBY0RhCShiJdw1mRUUxQxdkcV6XtBgZSyNNs/D2SpGluRc2jPmZSSZhbCAGjYhEpj42UpjU3gVMpCY1ScS9ryMPDn1Qtp30/VxMIGP8rFpVgQCsMQrFIWgSokcrUBKzwDAMXKzAsV07E4cqCCqwraXyEBbFsbhbAkcNkgkaFpEkTgxGkVQSpEcqfC4CQJAqrrSFqqxyqMEAVs6qxqtpOBYCQNAfHndgyAoCBTvO7MQGAfhbFIYNWAzYhttCtbagcVMyzW06fE3AB5WhWD%2B/byqwXINHYNb8A1ZAQRtbaIdIMD41MDMSva8h6EwYrUbzWpiF%2BzwMGsHHAl8bHCueuhGBYWGeAEYRxCkWR5AUNQNBQBq9FUPBam2yBaVQWYQXdEqAFpcgsUJbF2AoyzUfJMClktZWqVwZZwjEAnx7WgdsLbmssLgipKsrVtRjbZX4cMpfDERXHHSd%2BEGqlcEIEgllsTgKjJs7p2zX3OEaeq9AMDquvqHq%2BoG2xwwkMQRCd2xBAjJJ/YJ%2Bbreq9aSq2nbSD2g7SCOxAUFQIOLvISgbuD4h7pEURnunN6PtqL6fuIcGcYB4HQfB/OofUYBYdR%2BH4yRzAUfz9HkExinyv1gn86Jkne7JrAaZLoJFqsdraRoegmDYDhmaEURJBkTmubH3nI/5onhYgUXxcMlGdemTXkkdHWRh6zxrOKWRsTbmDNmHWapVyqVRtiVO2DsnYuwnK4EQ3BBDcGdhAL2RAcxtQDtXW6%2BDeC2F4OHPmuho4Q1jqQXq/VBr9SYcw5h0Dc5wPzhtIuu0Y4WysLwWBa0uEl14aQG071DIgBEEAA%3D):

```
# gcc8.3 -O3 -march=skylake-avx512 or -march=knl  (and -masm=intel)
add(long long __vector, long long __vector):
        mov     eax, -21846
        kmovw   k1, eax         # compiler-generated
       # inline asm starts
        vpaddd zmm0 {k1}{z}, zmm0, zmm1;  # conditional add   
       # inline asm ends
        ret
```

**`-mavx512bw` (implied by `-march=skylake-avx512` but not `knl`) is required for `"Yk"` to work on an `int`**.  If you're compiling with `-march=knl`, integer literals need a cast to `__mmask16` or `__mask8`, because `unsigned int = __mask32` isn't available for masks.

`[mask]  "Yk" (0xAAAA)`  requires AVX512BW even though the constant does fit in 16 bits, just because bare integer literals always have type `int`.  (`vpaddd` zmm has 16 elements per vector, so I shortened your constant to 16-bit.)  With AVX512BW, you can pass wider constants or leave out the cast for narrow ones.

- gcc6 and later support `-march=skylake-avx512`.  Use that to set tuning as well as enabling everything.  Preferably gcc8 or at least gcc7.  Newer compilers generate less clunky code with new ISA extensions like AVX512 if you're ever using it outside of inline asm.
- gcc5 supports `-mavx512f -mavx512bw` but doesn't know about Skylake.
- gcc4.9 doesn't support `-mavx512bw`.

---

`"Yk"` is unfortunately not yet documented in https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Machine-Constraints.html.

I knew where to look in the GCC source thanks to Ross's answer on [In GNU C inline asm, what are the size-override modifiers for xmm/ymm/zmm for a single operand?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34459803/in-gnu-c-inline-asm-whatre-the-modifiers-for-xmm-ymm-zmm-for-a-single-operand)

Comment: Just to leave a comment for anyone interested. Here is a naive example on the "Yk" constraint and relevant effects. https://godbolt.org/z/B8VLPz

Comment: @tert: there was a bug in your function I only just noticed: you merge-mask (not zero-mask) into `sum`, but it's uninitialized and you used an output-only `"=v"` for it.  I updated my answer to zero-mask instead.  And point out some advantages of intrinsics, like letting the compiler use a broadcast load as a memory operand, which is probably very hard to let the compiler choose with inline asm.

Comment: This is correct. {z} is necessary. Thank you for pointing it out.

Comment: Is there a constraint to specify that an integer operand can NOT be a k register? I have a problem with the Clang compiler putting a k register into an inline assembly instruction that requires a g.p register. I don't know if this is a bug in Clang or I need to specify the register type.

Answer (score 6):

While it is undocumented, looking [here](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/gcc/config/i386/constraints.md#L81) we see:

> (define_register_constraint "Yk" "TARGET_AVX512F ? MASK_REGS :
>   NO_REGS" "@internal Any mask register that can be used as predicate,
>   i.e. k1-k7.")

Editing your godbolt to this:

```
asm(
"vpaddd %[SUM] %{%[k]}, %[A], %[B]" 
: [SUM] "=v"(sum) 
: [A] "v" (a), [B] "v" (b), [k] "Yk" (0xaaaaaaaa) );
```

seems to produce the correct output.

That said, I usually try to [discourage](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/DontUseInlineAsm) people from using inline asm (and undocumented features).  Can you use `_mm512_mask_add_epi32`?

Comment: Thank you for the answer and the suggestion. I am fully discouraged on this. But when it comes down to SIMD, its either intrinsics or inline asm. Both could produce pain. Understanding one a bit more just might help avoid the other. ; )

Comment: @tert: My advice: *understand* the asm design, then write C intrinsics that can compile to the asm you want.  Sometimes you have to look up the right names for intrinsic functions if you only remember the shorter + simpler asm mnemonics, but if you want to look at any serious performance tuning you know that the asm is what really matters, and stuff like https://agner.org/optimize/ or https://uops.info/ have instruction tables that use asm mnemonics.  And Intel's intrinsics finder is searchable by mnemonic to find intrinsics.

Comment: @tert: But it's still early days for AVX512 mask registers, so compilers almost always copy them to integer registers and back even if a single `kshift` or `kor` would have worked.  But Intel has finally added mask intrinsics that really do compile to mask instructions like `kadd`, so if you need to help the compiler make better asm you can use those.  Supported in current versions of all the major compilers.  [Missing AVX-512 intrinsics for masks?](//stackoverflow.com/a/45174179)