# Problem with FCMLE instruction in ARM assembly using aarch64-none-elf toolchain

Tags: c, assembly, gcc, arm, qemu

I am facing an issue with the FCMLE(Floating-point Compare Less than or Equal to zero) instruction in ARM assembly. I am using the aarch64-none-elf toolchain for my embedded software development, and the problem is that my compiler says that the *fcmle* instruction is not a SIMD vector register, but this is not true.

Here's a summary of my test code for fcmle:

```
#include <arm_neon.h>

bool test_fcmle(void)
{
    float32x4_t Vn  = { 1.5f,  1.1f, -3.5f, 0.0f};
    float32x4_t Vm1 = { 1.1f,  1.5f, -3.5f, 4.4f};

    asm volatile(
        "FMOV %s0, %s1\n" // Load Vn into the SIMD register
        "FCMLE %s0, %s0, %s2" // Compare Vn and Vm1
        : "=w" (Vn)
        : "w" (Vn), "w" (Vm1)
    );
    //...
    //Some comparison code to check the result
    //...
    return true;
}
```

I used the *fadd* instruction instead of *fcmle* to make sure the SIMD registers were working and the error in the compilation process went away and the program ran successfully.

**NOTE-1 :** My toolchain is up to date (Version: aarch64-none-elf-gcc version 12.3.1 20230626 (Arm GNU Toolchain 12.3.Rel1 (Build arm-12.35))).

**NOTE-2 :** In the "instruction-sets" document on the ARM Developer website, in the supported architectures section for the "fcmle" instruction it says "Architectures A64" but for "fadd" it says "Architectures v7, A32, A64".

**NOTE-3 :** After a successful compilation, I test the executable file generated on a QEMU(v7.1.0) machine. The QEMU machine emulates the ARM Cortex-A72.

**NOTE-4 :** The command I used to compile :

```
aarch64-none-elf-gcc -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -nostdlib -ffreestanding -march=armv8-a -O0 -g -c -o main.o main.c
```

Does anyone have any insights into why I might be encountering this error? Am I missing any configuration or have I misunderstood the usage of the FCMLE instruction with this toolchain?

**EDIT-1:** The error I get as a result of compilation when I run the above code snippet:

```
/tmp/cc4yEhOw.s: Assembler messages:
/tmp/cc4yEhOw.s:1839: Error: operand 1 must be a SIMD vector register -- `fcmle s0,s0,s1'
make: *** [Makefile:23: main.o] Error 1
```

**EDIT-2:** After the changes @Jester mentioned, the following code compiles successfully, but I didn't get the result I expected, all values in the vresult vector are 0.

```
#include <arm_neon.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include "uart.h"

bool test_fcmle(void)
{
    printUart0("Testing fcmle\n");

    float32x4_t Vn  = { 1.5f,  1.1f, -3.5f, 0.0f};
    uint32x4_t Vexpected = {0, 0, 0xFFFFFFFF, 0xFFFFFFFF};
    float32x4_t Vresult;

    asm volatile(
        "FMOV %s0, %s1\n" // Load Vn into the SIMD register
        "FCMLE %s0, %s0, #0.0" // Compare Vn and Vm1
        : "=w" (Vresult)
        : "w" (Vn)
    );

    for(int i = 0; i<4; ++i){
        printNumber("Actual   = ", Vresult[i]);
        printNumber("Expected = ", Vexpected[i]);
        if(Vresult[i] != Vexpected[i])
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}

int main()
{
    if(!test_fcmle())
        printUart0("Test failed\n");
}
```

Output of the code:

```
---------------------------------------------
Testing fcmle
Actual   = 0
Expected = 0
Actual   = 0
Expected = 0
Actual   = 0
Expected = 4294967295
Test failed
```

**EDIT-3 :** I added "#include <arm_neon.h>" directive

Comment: Use `gcc -S` to examine generated assembly code to see which side the error is on (compiler or assembler).

Comment: `FCMLE`, as you also quoted, only compares to zero. It does not compare two vectors. The syntax is `FCMLE Vd.T, Vn.T, #0.0`

Comment: Re “my compiler says that the fcmle instruction is not a SIMD vector register”: That is not what the compiler said. Why wouldn’t you copy and paste the exact text so that other people can see exactly what the compiler message was? Edit the question to provide a [mre].

Comment: @Jester I run the assembly function in a function in C code, so I don't have any assembly file other than startup.s. So I didn't understand how to run aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc -S.

Comment: @Jester I tried "FCMLE %Vd.t, %Vn.T, #0.0" instead of "FCMLE %s0, %s0, %s2" but I got this error; "error: invalid 'asm': operand number missing after %-letter"

Comment: The `Vd.T` is just placeholder from the manual. You want `FCMLE %s0, %s0, #0.0`

Comment: `gcc -S` will create the assembly file that the compiler normally pipes to the assembler. It's good for troubleshooting inline assembly.

Comment: @Jester: [FCMLE has a vector form](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ddi0602/2023-09/SVE-Instructions/FCMLE--vectors---Floating-point-compare-less-than-or-equal-to-vector--an-alias-of-FCM-cc---vectors--?lang=en) instead of the immediate compare to zero. OP calls the instruction “Floating-point Compare Less than or Equal to zero”, but the vector form, instead of immediate form, they show is accepted by the Apple clang 14.0.3 assembler.

Comment: Once again, provide a [mre]. Your code does not compile as shown; it is missing `#include` directives and possibly other things. When I modify it so it will compile, it compiles (and assembles) without complaint. So there is something different about what you are doing. Edit the question to provide **complete** source code that reproduces the problem.

Comment: @EricPostpischil the one you linked seems to take a predicate and two vectors, not 3 vectors? But yeah clang does accept it on godbolt. Edit: found the vector version in the manual :)

Comment: @EricPostpischil I did not declare the #include directives and main function(and other functions) because they are not relevant to the question that I asked. In addition, in the text of the question, I stated that the compilation was successful when I used the "fadd" instruction instead of "fcmle". I read the link you mentioned and there is a statement; "Eliminate any issues that aren't relevant to the problem." Please don't miss the focus of the problem!

Comment: @rusty_green: Providing a [mre] helps other people reproduce the problem so they can work with it. That makes it relevant. Refusing to provide a [mre] is a way to attract votes down and votes to close the question. The statement you cite to eliminate any issues that are not relevant does not override the statement at the top to “Provide all parts someone else needs to reproduce your problem *in the question itself*.”

Comment: @EricPostpischil There is nothing in the question text that prevents reproducibility. All toolchains that support ARMV8-A will be able to compile the code I mentioned. Mr. Jester answered the same question, could you please specify what you want me to add here? What is missing in the code snippet that you want me to add?

Comment: @EricPostpischil I have created a link for clarity, you can review the code here https://godbolt.org/z/e9M9q8b9e

Comment: Note that the `s` registers are scalars, that will only do a single element.

Comment: Re “could you please specify what you want me to add here?”: There should be one sequence of source code that can be compiled without any changes or insertions whatsoever. In the source code currently in the question, neither `bool` nor `printUart0` nor `printNumber` are defined, and there is no `main` routine.

Comment: Change `%s0`, `%s1`, and `%s2` to `%0`, `%1`, `%2`. I do not know what you think you are doing with the `s`, but those are not the right strings for the compiler to substitute the operands. The strings to use for the operands are `%0`, `%1`, and `%2`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil ok I simplified and edited the code as you mentioned. S means 32-bit scalar & single-precision float. After converting %s0,%s1,%s2 to %0,%1,%2 I tried to compile but I got the following error;  "the top half of a 128-bit FP/SIMD register is expected at operand 1 -- `fmov v0,v0'"

Answer (score 1):

`fcmle` is an alias for `fcmge` with reversed operands. Apparently gnu binutils currently does not support it (see [aarch64-tbl.h:3429](http://sourceware.org/git/?p=binutils-gdb.git;a=blob;f=opcodes/aarch64-tbl.h;h=dc72b13f5f7049bae18a63a5a3950013970c1d5a;hb=HEAD#l3429)) As a workaround you can use the `fcmge` directly. Try `FCMGE %s0, %s2, %s0` (notice last two arguments swapped).

Comment: Obviously instruction fcmge is not what I need. Also, I compiled the code after making the changes as you said(tried fcmge instead of fcmle), but I didn't get the result I expected. It returned 0 for all comparisons and I don't understand why.

Comment: @rusty_green Why is it not what you need?

Comment: @fuz Because I already use the vcgeq_f32() function instead of the "fcmge" instruction. What I need is to use the "fcmle" instruction and test it. Also the fcmge instruction did not give the results that I expected.

Comment: @rusty_green Again, the two are the same instruction, just with a different operand order.  Checking for a >= b is the same as checking for b <= a.

Comment: It is important not only to be able to compare (to find the logical truth), but also to prove that the desired instructions work. Well @fuz this is not my choice. I need to write a test function using the fcmle instruction and that's it.

Comment: @rusty_green Well, there is no such instruction.  It's just an alias for `fcmge` with flipped operands.

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the `FMOV` line. There is no need for it. You can freely specify input and output registers in `FCMLE`.

Change `%s0`, `%s1`, and `%s2` to `%0`, `%1`, and `%2`, respectively. `%s0` is not useful to you in GCC inline assembly (per comments, `s` is an undocumented modifier for the operand that gives a scalar part of the register, but you want a vector). The names of the operands to the inline assembly construct are, if not named explicitly, `%0`, `%1`, and `%2`. Simply using `FCMLE %0, %1, %2` may work. If it does not because your assembler does not support this form of the `FCMLE` pseudo-instruction, use `FCMGE %0, %2, %1`. Here is a demonstration:

```
#include <arm_neon.h>


static uint32x4_t foo(float32x4_t Vn, float32x4_t Vm1)
{
    uint32x4_t Vresult;
    __asm__ volatile(
            "FCMLE %0, %1, %2"
            : "=w" (Vresult)
            : "w" (Vn), "w" (Vm1)
        );
    return Vresult;
}


#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>


static bool test_fcmle(void)
{
    printf("Testing fcmle:\n");

    float32x4_t Vn        = { 35, 45, 55, 65 };
    float32x4_t Vm1       = { 36, 45, 54, 63 };
    uint32x4_t  Vexpected = { -1, -1,  0,  0 };
    uint32x4_t  Vresult;

    printf("\tVn        = ");
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) printf(" %10g", Vn[i]);
    printf(".\n");
    printf("\tVm1       = ");
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) printf(" %10g", Vm1[i]);
    printf(".\n");

    Vresult = foo(Vn, Vm1);

    printf("\tVexpected = ");
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) printf(" 0x%08x", Vexpected[i]);
    printf(".\n");
    printf("\tVresult   = ");
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) printf(" 0x%08x", Vresult[i]);
    printf(".\n");

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
        if (Vresult[i] != Vexpected[i])
            return false;
    return true;
}


int main(void)
{
    if (!test_fcmle())
        printf("Test failed.\n");
}
```

The output is:

```
Testing fcmle:
    Vn        =          35         45         55         65.
    Vm1       =          36         45         54         63.
    Vexpected =  0xffffffff 0xffffffff 0x00000000 0x00000000.
    Vresult   =  0xffffffff 0xffffffff 0x00000000 0x00000000.
```

Note: With Apple tools, I had to use `"FCMLE.4s %0, %1, %2"` rather than `"FCMLE %0, %1, %2"`.

I recommend naming the operands explicitly. This code uses the same names in assembly as the names in C:

```
static uint32x4_t foo(float32x4_t Vn, float32x4_t Vm1)
{
    uint32x4_t Vresult;
    __asm__ volatile(
            "FCMLE %[Vresult], %[Vn], %[Vm1]"
            : [Vresult] "=w" (Vresult)
            : [Vn] "w" (Vn), [Vm1] "w" (Vm1)
        );
    return Vresult;
}
```

Comment: `%s0` is a meaningful and valid construct (it's the 32 bit scalar reg for the argument), just not useful in this case.

Comment: Letters between the `%` and the number of `[name]` are modifiers.  See https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html#Generic-Operand-Modifiers and for example [In GNU C inline asm, what are the size-override modifiers for xmm/ymm/zmm for a single operand?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34459803) for the kind of stuff they can do.  Unfortunately the modifiers for ARM / AArch64 aren't in the manual so you'd have to dig into the GCC source to find where `s` is defined.  (Like in that x/y/zmm question before those were documented.)

Comment: Also maybe worth mentioning that if you're going to include `arm_neon.h` for `float32x4_t`, it's probably better to use `uint32x4_t vclezq_f32(float32x4_t a)` to compare against an immediate 0.0 for example, or `uint32x4_t vcleq_f32(
     float32x4_t a,
     float32x4_t b)` to compare two arbitrary vectors.  (https://arm-software.github.io/acle/neon_intrinsics/advsimd.html)

Comment: @EricPostpischi which toolchain did you use for compiling the code? I am using "gcc version 12.3.1" and I got this compilation error: `/tmp/cccjIT0L.s:1838: Error: invalid use of vector register at operand 1 -- fcmle v0,v0,v1'`. When I type fcmle.4s instead of fcmle, I got this error: `/tmp/cc8JYjm6.s:1838: Error: unknown mnemonic fcmle.4s' -- fcmle.4s v0,v0,v1'`

Comment: I used Apple Clang 14.0.3 targeting arm64-apple-darwin22.6.0. Did you try `fcmge` with the input operands swapped?

Comment: @EricPostpischil Yes, I tried both ways but I got the above errors. I think the problem is in the toolchain. How can I find out if the toolchain supports FCMLE instruction? My toolchain is `arm-gnu-toolchain-12.3.rel1-x86_64-aarch64-none-elf`

Comment: You have got some tool problem, and I do not know what it is. The closest I can get on [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/TYssT4z94) is happy to take `fcmle v0, v0, v1`. I am not set up to investigate the specific compiler and assembler you are using.